# VHDL test bench file not accepting all set of inputs

Tags: vhdl

My VHDL test bench here is not accepting the third set of inputs and is looping back to the start of the process. Please help me.

**Code**: (comp4bit.vhd)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--4 bit comparator
entity comp4bit is
port ( a, b: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
AgtB, AltB, AeqB: out std_logic);
end comp4bit;

architecture behavior of comp4bit is
begin

process (a,b)
begin

if (a>b) then AgtB <='1'; AltB <='0'; AeqB <='0';   --A is more than B
elsif (a<b) then AgtB <='0'; AltB <='1'; AeqB <='0';    --A is less than B
else AgtB <='0'; AltB <='0'; AeqB <='1';        --A is equal to B
end if;

end process;
end behavior;
```

**Code**: (comp8bit.vhd)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--8 bit comparator using 4 bit comparator as component
entity comp8bit is
port( a: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    AeqB: out std_logic ;
    AgtB: out std_logic;
    AltB: out std_logic);
end comp8bit;

architecture behavior of comp8bit is
signal AgtB1 , AgtB2 , AltB1 , AltB2 , AeqB1 , AeqB2 , sig1 , sig2: std_logic;

component comp4bit is
port( a: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    AeqB: out std_logic;
    AgtB: out std_logic;
    AltB: out std_logic);
end component ;

begin 
u1:comp4bit port map (a=>a(7 downto 4), b=>b(7 downto 4),
AeqB=>AeqB1, AgtB=>AgtB1, AltB=>AltB1); --Port map of first 4 bit comparator

u2:comp4bit port map ( a=>a(3 downto 0), b=>b(3 downto 0),
AeqB=>AeqB2, AgtB=>AgtB2, AltB=>AltB2); --Port map of second 4 bit comparator

AltB<=AltB1 or (AeqB1 and AltB2); 
AgtB<=AgtB1 or (AeqB1 and AgtB2);
AeqB<=AeqB1 and AeqB2;

END behavior;
```

**Test bench**:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std ;

--Test bench file for 8 bit comparator
entity tb_comp8bit is 
end tb_comp8bit;

architecture structure of tb_comp8bit is
component comp8bit is
port( a:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    b:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    AgtB: out std_logic;
    AeqB: out std_logic;
    AltB: out std_logic);
end component;

signal a, b : std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0) ;
signal AeqB, AltB, AgtB: std_logic;

begin 
Dut1: comp8bit port map(a=>a, b=>b, AeqB=>AeqB, AgtB=>AgtB, AltB=>AltB);

process
begin
wait for 0 ns; --simulating a<b
a<="11110000"; --a= F0 (Hex) or 240 (Decimal)
b<="01101111"; --b= 6F (Hex) or 111 (Decimal)
wait for 20 ns; --simulating a=b
a<="01110000"; --a= 70 (Hex) or 112 (Decimal)
b<="01110000"; --b= 70 (Hex) or 112 (Decimal)
wait for 30 ns; --simulating a>b
a<="10011111"; --a= 9F (Hex) or 159 (Decimal)
b<="01101010"; --b= 6A (Hex) or 106 (Decimal)
wait; --changed this line
end process;
end structure;

configuration tb_comp8bit_con of tb_comp8bit is
for structure
end for;
end tb_comp8bit_con;
```

**Output**: (Simulated for 100ns)

[Signal Waveforms](http://s28.postimg.org/mweto6wwt/task_1_final.png)
[image: link image]

**EDIT**: Fixed the problem by inserting another `wait;` after the third set of inputs, before ending the process.

Comment: Ayush, you can answer your own question.

Comment: You could also have had the third output show up while it was looping if the first wait statement had a value other than 0 ns;

Comment: And for what it's worth without the entity and architecture for comp4bit the problem you report as fixed in your EDIT can't be reproduced.

Comment: I have added the code David, and I didn't know if my reputation was enough to answer my own question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your "wait 0ns" at the begining, the simulation is running in loop so you are changing a and b at the same time if you don't wait...

Using wait 10ns before the first initialization can solve your problem or indeed putting a wait at the end of your third variables.